# Adverb or something "else"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What exactly is the functionality of ***else*** (as in "something else")?

Does it always modify an action?

Does it also sometimes qualify a noun?

Most common dictionaries seem content with defining *else* as an **adverb**, implying (and exemplifying) that it is modifying the action. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/else), [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/else), [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/else), [ldoce](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/else), …)

OTOH, some others are charitable enough to treat *else* as an **adjective** (at least in some instances).

At least one resource calls it a **determiner** as well (in BrE). ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/else)) Here it is listed primarily as an adjective instead.

Is *else* as in "… something else …" an adverb, an adjective, a determiner, or something else?

Answer (score -2):

1. First of all, we should answer the question "what is 'something  else' ?"

   - According to Oxford English Dictionary
     (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/something_else):

*something else*

***PHRASE***

informal

An exceptional person or thing.

- According to Cambridge Dictionary

***something else***

​is an idiom:

''unusual, especially extremely good or extremely bad:

This game is really something else!''
(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/something-else#cald4-1-1-1)

So, we have a phrase or an idiom.

2. Functionally this phrase is a predicative.
   The predicative can formally belong to any part of speech.
   As it's a phrasal predicative we can term the first element as a 'pronoun' and the second one - its 'modifier' which is defined as 
   "a word or phrase that is used with another word or phrase to limit or add to its meaning"
   (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/modifier?q=Modifier+)