# Function of Else

Tags: grammar

In the sentence, "Do you study anything else besides English?", what is the function of else? Is it an adjective? An adverb? And if it is an adverb, what does it modify? Thank you!

Comment: This _has_ been [asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492400/adverb-or-something-else), but only dictionary support was given for the answer. It requires an answer / debate from grammarians rather than lexicographers, as it's not an obvious one. I'm tempted to draw comparisons with determiners, showing contextual reference of a noun / pronoun referent. 'Do you study anything interesting?' has 'interesting' as a postmodifying adjective modifying 'anything'. (But then ...

Comment: I see semantics and the function of a word in communication as being just as important as distribution when considering POS.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I, too, am confused about the function of 'else' here.

Comment: The OED says: "A synonym of _other_, used in connexion with indefinite, relative, or interrogative pronouns, or with words or phrases equivalent to any of these, such as _anything, nothing, everything, anybody, some one_; also with _all, much, little, a great deal_. (In mod. language _else_ follows the pronominal word or phrase.)" As for part of speech, Determiner.

Answer (score -1):

> In the sentence, "Do you study anything else besides English?", what is the function of else?

The OED gives **else**, adv., adj., n., and conj. (different/other/additional)

**Part 1**

**The adjective**

One argument is that “else” is an adjective: (different/other/another/additional)

The meaning of "Do you study anything else?", is "Do you study anything **that is different/additional**?", and “anything” is a noun. Therefore, “else” is a post-positional adjective.

"Do you study anything  besides English?" shows “anything” to be a noun (in fact, an NP = determiner + noun.)

A: "Do you study maths?"

B: “No.”

A: "Do you study anything?"

B: “Yes, English.”

A: "Do you study anything else?" = "Do you study any different/other/another/additional subject?"

B: “Yes, I study French.”

In which we can see that “You” is the subject, “do study” the verb and “anything else” is the NP object.

With the addition of “besides English”, semantically, the theme is not “study”, it is “English” and “anything (noun)” is looking for alternatives/additions (within the category of nouns) to the noun *English*, and not an alternative or addition to, or modification of, the verb “study”.

**Part 2**

**The adverb**

The argument is that “else” is an adverb, and this is supported by OED, which classifies this use as an adverb, in the meaning of “otherwise / differently / additionally”.   Which gives the meaning of "Do you {otherwise study}/ {study in addition} anything?"

However, there is the adverb “elsewise” that, were it required, could be used.

> 1864   C. Dickens Our Mutual Friend (1865) I. i. xi. 97   Elsewise, the world got up at eight.

**Part 2a**

**The flat adverb**

If “else” is an adverb, then it is a flat adverb.

Whether The **flat** adverb exists is a matter for discussion but the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb states

> In English grammar, a flat adverb, bare adverb, or simple adverb is an adverb that has the same form as the corresponding adjective, so it usually does not end in -ly, e.g. "drive slow", "drive fast", but sometimes does, e.g. "drive friendly".
>
> Flat adverbs were once quite common but have been largely replaced by their -ly counterparts. In the 18th century, grammarians believed flat adverbs to be adjectives, and insisted that adverbs needed to end in –ly

*[That last sentence would have been better as* In the 18th century, grammarians believed flat adverbs to be adjectives, and insisted that **if a person wished to appear educated then their** adverbs needed to end in -ly.]

The alternative view is that these flat adverbs are, in many cases, resultative or depictive adjectives that are free modifiers of the clause in which they appear.

He shot her dead / He shot her fatally but *“He shot her deadly.”
She shouted herself hoarse / * She shouted herself hoarsely.

And we can see a difference in “He arrived drunk” and “He arrived drunkenly”

The flat adverb may still be encountered colloquially “He was dead accurate with his shot.” Or “Hold fast!”